# BackboneJS: route is changed but html is not displayed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

following is my view template abclistTemplate

```
<li>
<a id="details">

<h3 class="blue_txt"><%= detail1%></span></h3>
<div class="list_l_txt">
    <p>From: <span> <%= detail2%> </span></p>

</div>


</a>
</li>
```

I have following code in js file

```
 define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!views/abcListTemplate.html','views/abcDetailsView', 'app/utils'], function($, _, Backbone, tmpl_abcView,abcDetailsView, utils) {

var abcListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Setting the view's template property using the Underscore template method        
    template: _.template(tmpl_abcView),
    // View constructor
    initialize: function() {
        self = this;

    },
    // View Event Handlers
    events: {
        "click #details": "clickedDetails"
    },
    // Renders the view's template to the UI
    render: function() {            
        return $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model));
    },
    clickedDetails:function(){
        var self=this;            

        mainRouter.views.leaveDetailsView = new abcDetailsView({ model:this.model }).render();

        window.location.href="#leaveDetails";

    }
});
return abcListView;
 });
```

abcDetailView.html

```
<p><%=detail1%><p>
<p><%=detail2%></p>
<p><%=detail3%></p>
```

abcDetailView.js

```
  define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!views/abcDetailView.html','app/utils'], function($, _, Backbone, tmpl_abcDetailView,Utils) {

var leaveDetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Setting the view's template property using the Underscore template method        
    template: _.template(tmpl_abcDetailView),
    // View constructor
    initialize: function() {            
        console.log("init details")
    },
    // View Event Handlers
    events: {
    },
    // Renders the view's template to the UI
    render: function() {
        console.log("leavedetails");            
       return $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model));           

    }
});
return leaveDetailsView;
 });
```

router code

```
 define(function(require) {

var $ = require('jquery'),
        _ = require('underscore'),
        Backbone = require('backbone');
        LocalStorage=require('app/localStorage');

Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
    this.undelegateEvents();
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
    if (this.onClose) {
        this.onClose();
    }
};

var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // store the views in an object for later use
        this.views = {};
        this.collections = {};
    },
    // All of your Backbone Routes (add more)
    routes: {
        // When there is no hash bang on the url, the dataVisualizationView method is called
        "": "default",
        "abcDetails":"abcDetails",           

    },        
    default:function(){

            require(['views/defaultView/defaultView'],function(defaultView){
                _this.views.defaultView=(_this.views.defaultView)?_this.views.defaultView:new defaultView({el:$("#wrapper")});
                _this.views.defaultView.render();
            })

    },
    abcDetails:function(){

            require(['views/abcDetailsView/abcDetailsView'],function(abcDetailsView){
                _this.views.abcDetailsView=(_this.views.abcDetailsView)?_this.views.abcDetailsView:new abcDetailsView({el:$("#wrapper")});
                _this.views.abcDetailsView.render();

    }

});
// Returns the Router class
return router;
 });
```

route is changed in url but new html is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear as though you're actually using the router to change routes. The major purpose of the router is to allow your app to respond to URL changes, but in order to do so, you have to interact with the browser location through it, not directly through `window.location.href`. See [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Router).

Essentially, you have to start the router somewhere in your app, using `Backbone.history.start()`, instantiating your router with a routing for your fragment to the controller function for showing your new view, and then you can trigger routing changes by doing `router.navigate(fragment)`.

Comment: i have tried using mainRouter.navigate("abcDetails",{trigger:true}) but still url is changed but html of detail is not displayed

Comment: Tough to help without seeing how the router is wired up.

Comment: var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.views = {};
            
        },
        
        routes: {            
            "abcDetails": "abcDetails",
        },        
        
        abcDetails:function(){
             
                require(['views/abcDetailView/abcDetailView'],function(abcDetailView){
                    _this.views.abcDetailView=(_this.views.abcDetailView)?_this.views.abcDetailView:new abcDetailView({el:$("#wrapper")});
                    _this.views.abcDetailView.render();
             
        }

    });

Comment: Can you update your question? It's tough to refer between the code in your comment and the code in your question. Plus, SO strips the formatting in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an object for the router so that all the routes will be registered in the browser.

```
RouterEg = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
   "abcDetails":"abcCallBack"        
  },

  abcCallBack : function() {
      //create a object for your view and call render function of your view
  }     

 });

 new RouterEg();

 Backbone.history.start();
```

This will register your routes.

Now you can trigger it using

this.navigate("abcDetails",{trigger:true});

Make sure you are having a container where you are going to append ie $(this.el) while appending your html template.You can specify your el container in your view also.

```
var leaveDetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({

**el : $('#yourcontainer'),**

// Setting the view's template property using the Underscore template method        
template: _.template(tmpl_abcDetailView),   

// View constructor
initialize: function() {            
    console.log("init details")
},
// View Event Handlers
events: {
},
// Renders the view's template to the UI
render: function() {
    console.log("leavedetails");            
   return $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model));           

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

In your `abcDetails` methid, don't forget to call `el` too, when you want to render your view like this: `_this.views.abcDetailsView.render().el`. As `el` is actually the element representing your view.

And the do `var somerouter = new router;`, then after do `Backbone.history.start();`.

See if that works.